# Check if list element is the result of adding other elements from list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Given a list of integers like this:

```
[10, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 50]
```

I would like to know which elements (if there is any) are the result of adding other two (or multiple) elements from the list. In this case, the output would be like:

```
10 -> [5, 3, 2]
10 -> [7, 3]
10 -> [7, 2, 1]
5  -> [3, 2]
7  -> [5, 2]
3  -> [2, 1]
```

Is there an efficient way to get this output? Note that the input list could be a very large one.

Comment: still need this answered?

Comment: I didn't find any good solution so far, so yes, I would be helpful

Comment: Please clarify the following:: (1) list of integers can contain duplicate entries (2) list length is less than or equal to max_length. (3) Integer duplicates can or cannot be used to form solution value up to the maximum number of existing duplicates.  To clarify this last point let l = [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1]  yields an output of 4 -> [3,1], 4-> [2, 1,1], 3 -> [2, 1], 3-> [1, 1, 1]

Comment: (1) - Yes, the list could contain duplicates, your entry  [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1] is a possible one. (2) - max_length could be something around 1000 integers. (3) - Integer duplicates can be used to form solution value up to the maximum number of existing duplicates, so your output is correct

Answer (score 0):

Get all possible combinations of smallest to largest list, then compare the sum of each list, to each element in `lst` to see if they are the same, then print them out.

```
import itertools

lst = [10, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 50]

combs = []

for i in range(1, len(lst)+1):
    [combs.append(list(x)) for x in itertools.combinations(lst, i) if len(list(x)) > 1]

for i in lst:
    for c in combs:
        if sum(c) == i:
            print(i,c)
```

Note that this,

```
if len(list(x)) > 1
```

Gets rid of lists that just contain one number.

**Output**

```
10 [7, 3]
10 [5, 3, 2]
10 [7, 2, 1]
5 [3, 2]
7 [5, 2]
3 [2, 1]
```

Comment: did you want me to include the arrows?